# undefined reference to `Employee::getCount() error in my function

Tags: c++

This is my main file:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include"Employee.h"

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    cout << "Number of employees before instantiation of any objects is " << Employee::getCount() << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

This is my `Employee.h` file:

```cpp
#ifndef EMPLOYEE_H
#define EMPLOYEE _H

#include <string>

using namespace std;

class Employee
{
public:
    Employee( const string &, const string & ); // constructor
    ~Employee(); // destructor
    static int getCount(); // return number of objects instantiated
private:
    static int count; // number of objects instantiated
    string firstName;
    string lastName;
}; // end class Employee

#endif
```

And this is my `Employee.cpp` file:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include "Employee.h" // Employee class definition
using namespace std;

int Employee::count = 0; // cannot include keyword static

Employee::Employee( const string &first, const string &last )
    : firstName( first ), lastName( last )
{
    ++count; // increment static count of employees
    cout << "Employee constructor for " << firstName << ' ' << lastName << " called." << endl;
} // end Employee constructor

// destructor deallocates dynamically allocated memory
Employee::~Employee()
{
    cout << "~Employee() called for " << firstName << ' ' << lastName << endl;
    --count; 
} // end ~Employee destructor

int Employee::getCount()
{
    return count;
}
```

Does anyone know why there is an error in my `main()` function?

> undefined reference to `Employee::getCount()'

I have declared the static data member and the static member function inside the class, and define them outside the class. I have also included `Employee.h` in my main file and `Employee.cpp` file, but the program still does not run.

Comment: How do you compile your program?

Comment: The thing is that you have to include *both* cpp files in the build of a complete program. How to do that depends a lot on what environment you are using (which you forgot to tell us).

Comment: I'd be surprised if `<<''<<` compiles (it certainly confuses stack overflows syntax highlighting). Are you actually compiling `Employee.cpp`?

Comment: It does not compile: https://godbolt.org/z/7PPMbT556 The `''` empty char is invalid and the class does not have `firstName` and `lastName` members

Comment: I'm guessing that `<< ''` was meant to be `<< ' '` instead.

Answer (score 1):

1. You are not compiling the files in a proper manner, compiling it and executing it in a proper manner will resolve the issue.

   I used the clang compiler and I used the the following command.

   > clang++ -std=c++11  main.cpp employee.cpp
2. The other mistake is not including `const string` variables `firstName` and `secondName`. Including variables named `firstName` and `lastName` as demonstrated below will resolve this issue.

   ```cpp
   class Employee
   {
   public:
       Employee( const string &, const string & ); // constructor
       ~Employee(); // destructor
       static int getCount(); // return number of objects instantiated

   private:
       const string firstName, lastName; //Declaring const string type variables firstName and lastName
       static int count; // number of objects instantiated

   }; // end class Employee
   ```
3. You have to insert a whitespace in-between single-quotes in the `cout` statements in `Employee.cpp`:

   ```cpp
   cout << "~Employee() called for " <<''<< lastName << endl;
   ```

   to

   ```cpp
   cout << "~Employee() called for " <<' ' << lastName << endl;
   ```